# Is there a way to get the redirect history from a Tornado response?

Tags: python, tornado

I'm using python Tornado to perform asynchronous requests to crawl certain websites and one of the things I want to know is if a URL results in a redirect or what it's inital status code is (301, 302, 200, etc.). However, right now I can't figure out a way to find that information out with a Tornado response. I know a requests response object has a history attribute which records the redirect history, is there something similar for Tornado?

Answer (score 0):

Tornado's HTTP clients do not currently provide this information. Instead, you can pass `follow_redirects=False` and handle and record redirects yourself.